# How to handle and fix the issue in activemq , when some queue's got stuck after restarting?

Tags: activemq-classic, leveldb

We are using ActiveMQ-5.8.0 with 2 brokers as master slave. Few days back, due to power failure all systems went down.

After restarting the brokers, a part of the queues are in enqueued state and its not dequeuing. We tried restarting the brokers. But still it's not recovering dequeue for two types alone.

Is there any way to handle and fix this without losing the events?